# Nginx rate limiting, using multiple rate rules

Tags: networking, nginx, rate-limiting

Using nginx rate limiting, using this rule as an example:

`limit_req_zone $request_limiting_zone_key zone=request_limiting_search:20m rate=30r/m;`

This will set 30 requests per minute. However what if I wanted to stack a second rule, so the logic is "30 requests per minute, or 1 request per second. Whichever comes first"

The reason for this is we still want a cap of 30/min but there are some weird attempts that we're seeing a spam of 10x requests in a 1-2 second period. This causes some issues when requests come through that fast. **So we would like to limit users to 1 request a second, AND a cap of 30 per minute.**

I read the doc reference but didn't see much around stacking different rate rules.

Is this possible? If so, what would be the syntax?

Comment: I don't need multiple zones. I need multiple rules on the same zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is perfectly valid to apply multiple zones to the same block.** You may also create multiple zones that store requests for the very same key (typically [some prefix of client IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27749834)). It only costs minimal processing and memory.

The following will limit users, identified by  their network address, both in second and minute intervals - and allow them to temporarily exceed the defined limit for short *bursts*. You want to allow that, as it will make your website appear less broken for user with unreliable input devices and/or network access - they might issue the same request twice:

```
map $remote_addr $request_limiting_zone_key {
    # [..]
}
limit_req_zone $request_limiting_zone_key zone=request_limit_search_second:10m rate=1r/s;
limit_req_zone $request_limiting_zone_key zone=request_limit_search_minute:10m rate=30r/m;

 # [..]

location /search {
    limit_req zone=request_limit_search_second burst=3;
    limit_req zone=request_limit_search_minute burst=3;
}
```

That being said, if your web server cannot handle a short burst of search requests, maybe you are going to need to offload your search engine to some other machine or apply a different kind of rate limit. **You need a significant margin between typical human usage and usage which exceeds your machines ability** to keep up. Otherwise you might not find a safe value between annoying legitimate users and failing to restrict abusive/bot usage.

Comment: Oops, missed a crucial part: Without `burst` and/or `nodelay`, doing this is entirely pointless - the lower rate limitation would always trigger first.

Comment: Appreciate the concise direct answer + example + extra details making it a well rounded solution to the question. Also, no worries on the annoying legit users as th limits imposed are way outside a normal human-use scenario as we're getting several results per second and no bot should be traversing /search... (it's denied in robots). Again, appreciate the input and information.

Comment: If we add `burst`, "minutes" rule still has lower rate and still wins, doesn't it? "Seconds" rule accepts up to 3 requests per second (1 request in 333 ms) while "minutes" rule accepts up to 3 requests per 2 seconds (1 request in 666 ms). If both rules should allow request so that nginx accepts it, then "minutes" rule will always have priority, doesn't it?